# Is word "crap" considered a vulgarism?

Tags: expressions

Most common damn-words in English are of course the f-word and the s-word, which are - for my best knowledge - considered vulgarisms. The word "crap" may be used as a damn-word, however I'd bet, that it is not vulgar. Am I correct?

Comment: Some people can take offense at any word in the English language - and as English is a rather word-rich langugage (due to borrowing words from just about everywhere) there is much to be offended about. It's not so much *what* is said as *how* it is said. Stand on a street corner and angrily shout "Petunias!" or "Chrysanthemums!"and I'm sure you'll find yourself surrounded in short order by a bevy of such individuals who feel that your use of the name of a flower is unconscionably vulgar because "We all know what you meant!!!".

Comment: Like many semantic features, vulgarity or tabooness is not absolute but comes on a smoother scale. dirt, spoor, manure, feces, excrement, poop, crap, shit.  There's quite a leap in vulgarity from poop to crap and also from crap to shit. Formalizing the exact feeling of the situations where crap is used is difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meaning of *crap* is

- Something that is of extremely poor quality: nonsense; rubbish, junk.
- excrement: (in singular) an act of defecation.

The first meaning is similar to the use of the work *cock* in the following British English sentence:

> That's all a lot of cock.

The NOAD doesn't mark the second meaning of *crap* as vulgar, and I don't think it is interpreted as vulgar from people too.
To make a comparison, also the word *cock* is not considered vulgar, as it has other meanings apart *penis*.

Comment: Crap can also be used as a synonym for *absurdity* or *ridiculousness*. It also can be used as an exclamation, as in *Holy crap!*.

Comment: I think you're leaving out the interjection as Scott Mitchell pointed out above.

Comment: The phrase highlighted would actually be quite an unusual one, but makes perfect sense. A native English speaker might use it to add a small amount of comedy value to their complaint. One would also likely substitute 'lot' with 'load'.

Comment: "Cock" is definitely somewhat vulgar, except when referring to a male chicken. "Crap" is on a similar level. Neither should be used in polite company -- but polite company is becoming less and less common :D

Comment: I find that "vulgarism" is subjective. I grew up hearing "crap" as a euphemism for "sh**" and it was like an acceptable substitute word, but I was visiting a friend and his mother gave me a gentle correction when I used it, so she considered it, at least to some degree, vulgar. I think in that instance I was talking about a pro wrestler "beating the crap out of" someone. She suggested I use the word "stuffing" instead. (WOW, that was 30 years ago.)

Comment: Interestingly, I'd find it used for the second meaning far more vulgar than the first.

Answer (score 12):

I wouldn't label *crap* as vulgar by today's standards, but it isn't a word you'd want to use in a professional setting or with people who are prim and proper.

The word itself is used in a many different ways. **kiamlaluno** pointed out two popular usages:

> - Something that is of extremely poor quality: nonsense; rubbish, junk.
> - excrement: (in singular) an act of defecation.

But it is also used as an exclamation, as in:

> Holy crap, this test is difficult!

I do think that the word *crap* has become more acceptable over time. When I was a child in the 80s I once said, in front of a friend's mother, "This is crap," after seeing a long line at an amusement park. She gave me a very stern look and told me I should not use such vulgar language.

Another time I was helping a classmate clean out his desk and I said something along the lines of, "There is a lot of crap in here," and he shushed me as he was concerned that we would get in trouble if the teacher heard us using that word.

Comment: +1 for including it as an interjection.

Answer (score 10):

Well, it's *less* vulgar than its synonym "shit", and more vulgar than the term "junk" or "garbage", so it's a matter of scale. I wouldn't use "crap" in polite company, or when speaking to a customer.

Coincidentally, when broadcasting on TV or the Radio in the USA, it's OK to use the word "crap", but illegal to use the word "shit", so it doesn't need to be censored.

Answer (score 1):

If you are, or want to be perceived as, a mature, grown-up person, you will not use the word "crap".  It is understood to be another word for fecal matter. Why would you want to talk about what you do in the bathroom?  Yuck. I sure don't want to hear about it in polite convo. That's just gross. Keep it to yourself.