# Why is saying "cr@p" more socially acceptable than saying "sh!t" is?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, offensive-language

I know *shit* is generally considered vulgar swearing in any context, while *crap* (though it's normally used as a swear word) is often used and allowed in decent contexts.

How did this happen, since they both refer to the same thing?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12200/is-word-crap-considered-a-vulgarism

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cultural mores rather than English language

Comment: I'm not sure it's entirely off-topic; I interpreted it as asking about the history of the usage of certain swear words, which is (I believe) on-topic. It probably could use editing to better reflect that, though.

Comment: @Oldcat It does regard cultural mores, but it's primarily a question about the history of nuances attached to words of similar meaning. I'm not asking why forks go on the left. English wouldn't be much without cultural reference.

Comment: Added a relevant tag, since we have it.

Comment: Just about every adjective you use in your question is related to cultural mores:  "decent", "vulgar" and so on.  Not about the nuances of the definition of the two words, which you say are the same.

Comment: I'm not asking about nuances of definition, I'm asking about nuances of usage, specifically the history. I agree that this question regards cultural mores, but that is part of every language.

Comment: _Crap_ is a recent word, an old word for 'chaff' that became a euphemism for _shit_ in the 19th century. It became associated with the Crapper brand of flush toilet and has held on since. It's what George Carlin calls a "two-way word", in that it has a non-taboo meaning as well: "You can prick your finger, but you can't finger your prick". Then there is the dice game called "craps", where losing is called "crapping out". _Shit_ has none of these ramifications; shit is just shit.

Comment: Defined “swearing”.

Comment: @tchrist - Your description of your edit says "no Bonderization in text". Dictionary.com defines ['bonderize'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bonderize) as "to coat (steel) with an anticorrosive phosphate solution, usually in preparation for the application of paint, enamel, or lacquer." I assume the word you were after was [*bowdlerization*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bowdlerize). Personally, I don't think that titles should be bowdlerized either.

Comment: @ErikKowal The position of the The Powers That Be has long been clear on this. ⓵ Leave no unfiddled “rude” words in post titles due to unfavorable algorithms in search engines and nannyware. ⓶ They’re ok as literals in the body of the post — ***provided*** one stick strictly to the *mention* side of the use–mention distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prof. Lawler provided an excellent answer in a comment:](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182101/why-is-saying-crp-more-socially-acceptable-than-saying-sht-is#comment378622_182101)

> *Crap* is a recent word, an old word for 'chaff' that became a euphemism for *shit* in the 19th century. It became associated with the Crapper brand of flush toilet and has held on since. It's what George Carlin calls a "two-way word", in that it has a non-taboo meaning as well: "You can prick your finger, but you can't finger your prick". Then there is the dice game called "craps", where losing is called "crapping out". *Shit* has none of these ramifications; shit is just shit.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between proper words, euphemisms, and vulgar words is practically always about the specific word, not the meaning. And the acceptability of specific words changes over time. The whole reason that euphemisms exist is to provide an acceptable replacement for some rude term, because it's sometimes necessary to refer to things. So while we would generally prefer to avoid talking about defecation, if you do have to say it you should choose the less vulgar term.

Why does it matter? Choosing words properly is considered a signal of culture. Watch *My Fair Lady* for a classic demonstration.

A good book about euphemisms is [Euphemania: Our Love Affair with Euphemisms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316056561) by [Ralph Keyes](http://www.amazon.com/Ralph-Keyes/e/B001IOF5ES/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1).

Comment: I like your answer, but it doesn't address the specific history of crap/shit, why one is more vulgar.